# Nested Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can create a nested CheckBoxList in ASP.NET, assuming that the depth is not specified(depth is more than 2!)?  I can't use a repeater.

Ok add some details:

I have a table named Employee with following fields:

ID    Name    BossID

which BossID is an ID of  an Employee. So we have One-To-One relationship. So every Employee must have a boss( Except Big boss) and this make a child and parent model.
Now i want when a user click a boss checkbox, all of his employee will be checked.

Comment: Would you be showing the nested list if the parent list equaled some value? Or are you always showing nested lists?

Comment: @gunr2171 I want to always showing nested list.

Comment: Have you considered a treeview?  It might be less work to code up

Comment: @DanPichelman can you show me a sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to write some code to nest your checkbox lists within a div or some other containing tag.

I would suggest you make a control to help isolate out the code so you don't have it jumbled up with your existing code. Your control should only have a single `asp:Panel` in it. Also have a property to pass in the items in nested structure (my guess is a `Dictionary<string, int>` but you will have to decide that)

In your `Load` event, create the CBL and sub-containers (divs) on the fly and attach them to the panel. The order should be:

```
asp:Panel
    CheckBoxList 1
    div
        CheckBoxList 2
        div
```

You can see how this might get complicated fast.

The last thing to do is make sure you add `SelectedIndexChanged` event listeners to all your checkbox lists.

[This Post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1458411/3346353.aspx/1?Re%20Nesting%20RadioButtonList) might have some more information to help you.

Comment: First of all, I need nested checkboxlist. But, it actually does not work! Because it just nest the whole of list!

Comment: It does what? My mistake about the radiobutton/checkbox, but what was that second part? And I think you still being very vague in your requirements for this.